# Connect from win11 host to ruby container in WSL2

Tags: ruby, windows, docker, wsl-2

I have a ruby app running inside a container launched from WSL2.
Docker start perfectly and from the log of the container everything seems fine:

```
2023-12-06 14:18:51 * Puma version: 5.3.2 (ruby 2.7.7-p221) ("Sweetnighter")
2023-12-06 14:18:51 *  Min threads: 5
2023-12-06 14:18:51 *  Max threads: 5
2023-12-06 14:18:51 *  Environment: development
2023-12-06 14:18:51 *          PID: 1
2023-12-06 14:18:51 * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
2023-12-06 14:18:51 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

if I open a browser from the host (win11) and try to navigate to localhost:3000 or to wsl2 ip -> 10.5.0.2:3000 I always get "Connection refused"

executing ifconfig inside wsl2 give me this result:

```
eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether xxxxxxxxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 164  bytes 8633 (8.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19  bytes 1899 (1.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1420
    inet 10.5.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.5.255.255
    inet6 xxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether xxxxxxxx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1101  bytes 654301 (654.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 377  bytes 77929 (77.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

loopback0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:15:5d:53:5d:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 11079  bytes 12003182 (12.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3720  bytes 11517488 (11.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

eth2 is the host's IP while eth3 is the wsl2's IP.

Maybe the problem is due to the missing eth0?

**Edit**
If I run the same docker compose from a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu, everything works fine

Comment: How did you start the container?  Do you have a `docker run -p` or equivalent option to publish a container port to the host?

Comment: I have a docker compose that expose port 3000

Comment: `expose:`, or `ports:`?  `expose:` doesn't actually do anything, and I'd suggest deleting it if you have it.  You need `ports:` here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not using the correct language. The docker compose uses `ports: - 3000:3000`